# Chart Js: How to display data values in chart js bars

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-dom, chartjs, chartjs-plugin-datalabels

I have built simple bar chart with ChartJS version v2.8.0, so now I am trying to display the data values on each bars using chartjs-plugin-datalabels v1.0.0 plugins [chartjs-plugin-datalabels](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels/tags) I have loaded this plugin as below in the code and registered the plugin as specified in the [plugin documentation](https://v1_0_0--chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/guide/getting-started.html#registration)
but however the data values are not showing up on each bars.

Can anyone point out what am I missing here? that would be helpful

Here is the LwC code:

```
import { LightningElement,api, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import chartjs from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/chartjs_v280';
import ChartDataLabels from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/ChartjsPluginDataLabels';
import { loadScript } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';

export default class ChartDemocmp extends LightningElement {
    isChartJsInitialized;
    chartConfiguration;

    connectedCallback(){
        this.setData();
    }

    setData(){
        this.chartConfiguration = {
            type: 'bar',
    data: {
     labels: ["data1","data2","data3","data4","data5","data6","data7"],
     datasets: [
      {
       label: 'dataset',
       barPercentage: 0.5,
       barThickness: 6,
       maxBarThickness: 8,
       minBarLength: 2,
       backgroundColor: "blue",
       data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
      },
     ],
    },
    plugins: [ChartDataLabels], //plugin register
    options: {
        resposive:true,
    },
   };
   console.log('chart data---> '+JSON.stringify(this.chartConfiguration));
}
    

    renderedCallback() {
        /*if (this.isChartJsInitialized) {
            return;
        }*/
        // load chartjs from the static resource
        Promise.all([
            loadScript(this, chartjs)
        ])
        .then(()=>{
            //load ChartDataLabels from the static resource
        Promise.all([
            loadScript(this, ChartDataLabels )
        ])
        .then(() => {
            console.log('Loaded');
            this.isChartJsInitialized = true;
            
            if(this.chart!= null || this.chart!=undefined){
                this.chart.destroy();//destory the chart once data is updated to show the new chart
                }
        const ctx = this.template.querySelector("canvas.barChart").getContext('2d');
        this.chart = new window.Chart(ctx,JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.chartConfiguration)));
        //console.log('data chart');
        });
    })
        .catch(error => {
           console.error('error chart--> '+JSON.stringify(error))
            
        });
    
    }

    
    
    }
```

Here is the screen shot of bar chart where the values are not getting displayed on each bars:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `Chart.register` to register the plugin.

```
Chart.register(ChartDataLabels);
```

Also, you should be able to import both at the same time, to decrease loading time:

```
Promise.all([
    loadScript(this, chartjs),
    loadScript(this, ChartDataLabels)
]);
```

[Demo](https://studio.webcomponents.dev/edit/dyV5IyWxHrwlFjWSSQpf/src/app.js?p=stories).

Comment: thanks for the reply, I have followed your approach, so when I try to register using 'Chart.register(ChartDataLabels)' I am getting the following error as 'Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: d.default.register is not a function
    at eval'

Comment: @Sagar Interesting. I'm not sure what else to say at the moment, you'll want to try debugging. It might be a missing dependency or something. Have you tried building it from scratch? Also, have you tried just using it as an ES6 module, as demonstrated in this answer? Many libraries that are ES6 compatible work well in LWC; you just have to copy-paste the source into a JS file, then import it as normal.

Comment: I was able to resolve this error 'Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: d.default.register is not a function at eval', and I was able to display the chart, but still the labels are not getting displayed on the bars

Comment: Finally I was able to resolve it, thanks for the suggestion @sfdcfox

Comment: @sagar Posting how you were able to resolve these errors would've been helpful. I'm getting similar error when adding `Chart.register(ChartDataLabels)`